# Magical Sword lightings Help

Tags: magical, electricity, lighting, singing-sword

Hey guys, I'm new here, this is my first post.

I'm working on this animated project in wich the main character has a magical sword that emits lighting bolts and sparks and shines like it has some kind of energy field...

I believe I'm halfway through but I have a problem. I did this chime-like atmosphere and added some buzz with some synthesizers to create the energy field (listen here please, https://www.dropbox.com/s/qw41nm3g2yxl2tk/magic_sword_efield.wav any recommendation would be also much appreciated)... but I'm getting nowhere trying to create the lighting bolts/sparks...

I saw the Tonsturm electricity library but I have no $$ right now. I searched in the Buzzsaw 2 from Blastwave FX but the sounds are already heavily processed... pretty useless for what I need. I would love to record them myself but honestly I'm not to good handling electrical things (I don't want to die getting zapped or burned by myself...). So, if you could help me getting ideas on how to create something similar processing other sounds, create them with fooley that does not include deadly AC or with some synthesizers would be much appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hey guys

Thanks for all the ideas! I managed to get away with it recording some electrical shavers and the microwave! Still I will make that pickup device because it looks like I could get some crazy sounds out of it.

thanks!

Comment: post a clip? would like to see how it turned out


Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about searching out some tesla coil samples and some industrial like arc welder sounds? Soundsnap is usually like a buck a sound if you find something you like or freesound.org.

I love filtering my microwave for some weird forcefieldy sounds. It's just the right amount of air and ominous buzz.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to touch or handle 'electrical things' check out this blogpost by jedsound (jean edouard miclot). He record electromagnetic sounds with guitar pick-ups.
http://jedsound.com/blog/?p=200

good luck

Answer (score 0):

I mixed static noise recorded from a radio tuned on a silent channel with synthesized material to get "energy"-type sounds.